# MySQL JSON Extraction with Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to extract the latitude and longitude fields stored in this address JSON:

```
 {
    "city": "Hamilton", 
    "name": "22 Fake Road", 
    "type": "address", 
    "value": "22 Fake Road, Hamilton, Ontario, Canada", 
    "latlng": {"lat": 42.2526, "lng": -69.8549}, 
    "country": "Canada", 
    "postcode": "L3Q 2W1", 
    "countryCode": "ca", 
    "administrative": "Ontario"
 }
```

I'm trying to pull the name, latitude, and longitude for a map dashboard. I've tried both an eloquent query, and a raw SQL query:

```
 $mapmarkerscalc = DB::table('potentialcustomers')->select('name', 'address->latlng->lat', 'address->latlng->lng')->get();
 $mapmarkers = collect($mapmarkerscalc);

 $mapmarkerscalc2 = DB::raw("SELECT (name, JSON_EXTRACT(`address` , '$.latlng.lat'), JSON_EXTRACT(`address` , '$.latlng.lng')) FROM potentialcustomers");
 $mapmarkers2 = collect($mapmarkerscalc2);
```

They both get pretty close, but return a bunch of unneeded data in the `"lat"` and `"lng"` field:

```
{
   "name":"Fake Company",
   "`address`->'$.\"latlng\".\"lat\"'":"43.1526",
   "`address`->'$.\"latlng\".\"lng\"'":"-79.8559"
}
```

How can I get rid of `"`address`->'$.\"latlng\".\"lng\"'":"`??

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store both longitude and latitude in two different columns in the MYSQL database, it will be much easier if not impossible to get the data values.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have:

```
{
   "lnglat": "{"lng":2,"lat":23}"
}
```

You can use the:

```
 json_decode($data->lnglat, true);
```

and after that you can get :

```
 {{ $data['lng'] }}
```

and

```
{{ $data['lat] }}
```